# If $\{x_n\}$ is unbounded and $x_{n+1}-x_n\to0\ (n\to\infty)$, does this imply $|x_n|\to\infty\ (n\to\infty)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

What my question is: the following is right or wrong:
$$ \{x_n\}\ \text{is unbounded and }(x_{n+1}-x_n)\to0\ (n\to\infty)\implies|x_n|\to\infty\ (n\to\infty).$$
I can argue that if $\{x_{n_k}\}$ satisfies
$\lim_{k\to\infty}|x_{n_k}|=\infty$,
then, for any positive integer $m$,
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}|x_{n_k+m}|=\infty.$$
But it is not clear to imply $|x_n|\to\infty\ (n\to\infty).$
Any help or hints will wellcome!

Answer (score 3):

You can construct a counterexample like this:

- Start with $x_0 = 0$.
- Increment in steps of $1$ until you reach the value $1$, i.e. $x_1 =1$.
- Decrement in steps of $1/2$ until you reach the value $-2$, i.e. $0.5, 0, -0.5, -1, -1.5, -2$.
- Increment in steps of $1/3$ until you reach the value $3$.
- Decrement in steps of $1/4$ until you reach the value $-4$.
- ... and so on.

The sequence $(x_n)$ is unbounded, and $x_{n+1} - x_n$ converges to zero. But $x_n = 0$ for infinity many $n$, so that $(|x_n|)$ does not converge to $\infty$.

Comment: Nice construction!

Comment: In your given $\{x_n\}$, does the limit points set of $\{x_n\}$ is $[-\infty,\infty]$.

Comment: @Riemann: Yes. Generally, if $\liminf x_n = -\infty$ and $\limsup x_n = +\infty$ and $x_{n+1} - x_n \to 0 $ then the set of limit points is $[-\infty,\infty]$.

Comment: Thank you for you point that!

Comment: @Riemann: Or this: If $x_{n+1} - x_n \to 0$ then the set of limit points is equal to $[\liminf x_n, \limsup x_n]$, see  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2666730/42969 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3195189/42969.

Comment: Thanks @Martin R I know above result you point when $\{x_n\}$ is bounded . I am not clear the situation when $\{x_n\}$ is unbounded.

Comment: @Riemann: The proofs in those answers from my previous comment work also if the sequence is unbounded below and/or above.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the sequence
$$ x_n:=n^{1/3}\sin(n^{1/3}).$$
This sequence is such that $x_{n+1}-x_n$ goes to $0$ (because the derivative of the function $f(x)=x^{1/3}\sin(x^{1/3})$ goes to $0$ for $x\to+\infty$), but it is unbounded and oscillates (this comes from the fact that, again, $f’(x)\to 0$ for $x\to +\infty$ and that $f$ itself is unbounded and oscillating for $x>0$; I can give more details if you want).

Comment: I would modify this slightly to $x_n =n^{1/3}\sin(\pi n^{1/3})$, so that $x_{k^3} = 0$.  That makes is a bit simpler to argue why $|x_n|$ does not converge to $\infty$.

Comment: Thanks @Martin R

Comment: Thanks @Lorenzo Pompili

Comment: Or $x_n =n^{1/3}\sin(n^{1/3} \pi/2)$. Then $x_{(2k)^3} = 0$ and $x_{(2k+1)^3} = \pm (2k+1)$.

Comment: @Martin R If $x_n =n^{1/3}\sin(\pi n^{1/3})$, what is the limit points set about $\{x_n\}$?

Comment: @MartinR , very nice. Riemann, this is a sequence that is unbounded from above and from below, and $x_{n+1}-x_n$ goes to $0$. So, as Martin observed, the limit points set is again $[-\infty,+\infty]$